# Makefile Substituting for loop variables to functions

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm not sure what the best way to do this, and some pointers in this regard would be helpful

### Code:

```
#Else where in different file and included in this makefile i have
LIBRARY_LIST    := CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS
CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS :=  y

    collect-compilation:
        if  [   $(strip $(CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS)) ==  y   ]; then \
            echo "ok";  \
        fi;
        for compile in $(LIBRARY_LIST)  ;   do  \
            if  [   $(strip $$compile)  ==  y   ]; then \
                echo "ok";  \
            fi; \
        done
```

So from the above code snippet., the top part the 'IF' loop works fine as expected and i see 'OK'.
displayed.

Now for the second for-loop, i have some problems substituting the $$compile to the 'IF'. Eventually i expect $$compile gets replaced by CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS and the expression should evaluate to y == y and display 'OK' but for me.,

### Output:

```
make -C ./Dev2.0.1/OSX
if  [   y   ==  y   ]; then \
        echo "ok";  \
    fi;
ok    <----- fine and expected
for compile in CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS  ;   do  \
        if  [   $compile    ==  y   ]; then \
            echo "ok";  \
        fi; \
    done      <------ Here it skips the then part and proceeds further, i expect 'OK' after this though.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're mixing Make-expansion and shell-expansion.

We start with this command:

```
    for compile in $(LIBRARY_LIST)  ;   do  \
        if  [   $(strip $$compile)  ==  y   ]; then \
            echo "ok";  \
        fi; \
    done
```

Make expands the variables:

```
    for compile in CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS  ;   do  \
        if  [   $compile  ==  y   ]; then \
            echo "ok";  \
        fi; \
    done
```

(note that `compile` has no value yet) and passes the command to the shell, which expands the variables, runs the `for` loop and winds up testing:

```
        if  [   CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS  ==  y   ]; then
```

which clearly must fail. It is too late to expand `CONFIG_MTS_PTHREADS`; the shell doesn't know that it's a variable with a value. Make knew, but Make has already handed to command off to the shell.

One solution is to use the `value` function, so that Make will expand the variable before passing it to the shell:

```
    for compile in $(value $(LIBRARY_LIST))  ;   do  \
        if  [   $(strip $$compile)  ==  y   ]; then \
            echo "ok";  \
        fi; \
    done
```

Comment: No, `$(value ...)` won't help here.  That's just a way to _avoid_ recursive evaluation.  Here, you _want_ recursive evaluation.  You'll need something like: `for compile in $(foreach V,$(LIBRARY_LIST),$($V)) ; do` so that make expands each word in LIBRARY_LIST as a make variable.  Otherwise, your explanation is spot-on!

Comment: Amazing explanation!., Thanks a ton., actually value worked., but i think i will do the for each version, because i will in future have more words in the LIBRARY_LIST and i need make to understand each word., sounds a better fit for my purpose. Thank you so much all!

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice LIBRARY_LIST is expanded when given to value.  This will work... unless LIBRARY_LIST is recursive and itself contains variable references.  The foreach version works even in that case.

Comment: @MadScientist: Praise from Caesar! But now I'm kicking myself for not thinking of `$(foreach...$($V))`.